# CentOS need explanation about semanage ... http_port_t

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

I came across the following command

```
semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 5500
```

However this argument "http_port_t" doesn't exist, what I understand from this error.

[image]

What else can be used instead of http_port_t? Or if there is any need? Because without this command my http service works fine. i.e.
`service http restart` generates no error as it is supposed to for that port.

I am using CentOS 7.9

Comment: [Here's an article that explains what `semanage port -m` is doing.](https://linoxide.com/use-semanage-command-selinux-policy/) I don't know why it's throwing that error or why you need http to accept port 5500.

Comment: Also see the [semanage-port man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/semanage-port.8.html).

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask].

Comment: You probably need to use `-a` (add) instead of `-m` (modify), I think the error message is misguiding.